# Possible Memory Leak with prepared statements?

Tags: php, sql, memory-management, memory-leaks, prepared-statement

## Background:

I am trying to learn prepared statements, and this one is throwing an error I would like to learn how to fix.

The data in the Item table is inputted by users which is why I am using a prepared statement for this one as well, and well... the practice of course..

I spent about an hour searching this site, and most sites are recommending changing the memory limit to a higher value.. I don't think this would be required, as the table I am selecting has very few rows..

## Purpose of query:

The user loads the page, and it will list out the items. From here they can purchase said items with points they acquire from participating in a program we run.. This is the query to list the items..

## Here is the Error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 201326592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in (Removed, but is location of file) on line 80

## Line 80:

```
$Select_stmt2->bind_result($Item_Key, $Item_Image, $Item_Name, $Item_Amount, $Item_Describe);
```

## Extra Information:

Also the $conn variable is pulled from a second configure.php file during the header. I will display it minus the info to connect to the server.

```
//Connect to Database
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'Username', 'Password', 'Table Name');
```

## Code:

```
//Item Points
            $Enabled = 'Enabled';

            $Select_Query2 = "SELECT Item_Key, Item_Image, Item_Name, Item_Amount, Item_Describe FROM Item WHERE Item_Status = ?";
            $Select_stmt2 = $conn->prepare($Select_Query2);
            $Select_stmt2->bind_param('s',$Enabled);
            $Select_stmt2->execute();

            $Select_stmt2->bind_result($Item_Key, $Item_Image, $Item_Name, $Item_Amount, $Item_Describe);
            if(!$Select_stmt2)
            {
                echo'Error: Selecting Items';
            }
            else
            {
                /* Code to display the data for line 80 on the website */
            }
```

Comment: What is the description of your Item table? Do you get the same error if you select each item individually?

Comment: Are you running `$conn->prepare` inside a loop?

Comment: Are you storing images as BLOB's?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Your question pointed the way.  Item_Describe was set as a longblob.. and I chaned it to varchar and it worked as intended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have blob column? The number 4294967296 indicates you are trying allocate memory for max length of blob column. It can be  a bug but not a leak, and the culprit could be the bind statement. If you have a blob column and it keep giving error, try cast it a varchar in your select statement.

Comment: Item_Describe was set as a longblob.. and I changed it to varchar and it worked as intended.  Thanks for the help.